# PHP create image file using imagecreatefromstring, without knowing the format of the image

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a laravel RESTful app that accepts image strings from users and must store them. 
images are encoded and sent to my app. I know that I have to Receive and decode  image like this:

```
$imageData = base64_decode($imageData);
$source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
```

but I dont know how to save them to files, without **knowing the format** of the image?is there any way to find out the image extension, so that I can use functions like:
imagepng

Comment: Check the raw string for magic bytes (`APNG`, `GIF89`, `JFIF`, etc.), using e.g. `finfo` or `exif_imagetype`. There's no need to instantiate a GD instance unless you modify/rescale the stored images.

Comment: can you give me a sample code?

Comment: Is it important to know/get the image format or you simple need to save this as an image? If you don't care about the format you can simple use `imagepng($source, 'path/filename.png')` and save that image as png

Comment: I can ask the android developer to send me the format of image, but I thought that it would be better, if I could find out the image format from string of that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getimagesizefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php);

```
$size = getimagesizefromstring($imageData);
if ($size['mime'])
   return $size['mime'];
```